# Best way to share a folder for IIS WebApplication

Tags: iis, load-balancing

Currently I've got 2 IIS that are balanced via HAProxy and each one releis to a local folder on the Windows Server local disk. This leads me to solution update problem's since when I've to update a project I've to update both .
I know that having a shared folder on a network folder is not a good solution....is there a better way of handling such a scenario? Please consider that in a short I'll have 3 IIS nodes and so mantaining everything allingned becomes difficult

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you're trying to accomplish.

If you're updating data on the file system, then having a shared network folder is the way to go. That's what I do.

But, If you're just trying to keep your "Static Code" in sync across your cluster then you can use replication tools to keep the code in sync. I use something called repli-web. So I just drop it on the master IIS Node in repli-web and then it will sync it across the cluster.

Comment: Hello Henry, for now I've managed using robocopy, but I don't like this a lot... I would have used your approach but I've read some time ago that putting Web Application's code in a network shared folder is evil....

Comment: I think you might of mis-understood me. When I use shares, it's not for the application code, but for file that a customer uploads or saved PDF's for the customer. This way those files are stored in a single location and accessible to the customer. So I will have a virtual folder in IIS pointing to the share and the application will reference it to retrieve that information.  As for the application code, I replicate it and keep it in sync via repli-web, It's just one of the many features of repli-web I use.